# Earbud wire color shielding is red/white and yellow/black, which are the grounds?

Tags: analog

All wires are white metal, no copper, and they run side-by side and not one inside the other, ground.

I'm trying to - well, will - hack my laptop via the headphone jack (yuck) into a Yamaha YAS-71 analog inputs because I apparently don't have optical outs on my laptop, an older HP.

Comment: Can't afford the correct 3.5mm cable adapter??

Answer (score 0):

Probably white and black, although it shouldn't really matter, assuming that the earbuds are *passive*, as the speakers in the earbuds are basically just a coil and there is no directional preference in which direction the current flows.

It would be best to test them briefly, by connecting to an audio source and seeing which way around the music sounds better. So long as the volume on the output is low, then no damage should occur.

Comment: "it shouldn't really matter, assuming that the earbuds are passive, as the speakers in the earbuds are basically just a coil and there is no directional preference in which direction the current flows." From what I've read, phasing in headphones is not nearly as critical a with speakers, but it can be noticeable. The symptoms seem to be loss of center image and general muddiness. YMMV.